# Как сделать ssl для другого порта?

Tags: http, debian, ssl, https

У меня есть домен, например, `https://site.com`. на нем установлен ssl сертификат. Мне нужно, что бы на другом порту работал другой сервис. Например, что бы он открывался `https://site.com:8000`. Проблема в том, что он открывается на `http`, а на `https` не хочет.

Вопрос: ssl не действует на другие порты?

Comment: Действует. А сервер-то какой?

Comment: Действует. А вы настроили https на сервере на порту 8000?

Comment: система - debian, стоит apache+nginx. если честно, я не знаю как настраивать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: server { listen 8000 ssl; ....} в конфиге nginx

Comment: настраивается точно так же, как настроено для 443-го порта, только для 8000-го.

Comment: всем спасибо, вышло сделать